# Drag and Drop in cypress (trigger pointermove, {eventconstructor: PointerEvent}

Tags: javascript, cypress, drag, drop

I want to drag an object in cypress but after dragging i faced this error in cypress running window. Error is (
trigger
pointermove, {eventconstructor: PointerEvent})
**my code is**

```
type Url = string
       it('Drag', () => {
       cy.visit(url)
       cy.get('.sourceitem').drag('.targetitem');

      cy.get('[disabled]').click({force: true})

        })
```

[image]